# HTTP status code

Tags: asp.net, http

How to get HTTP status code id from object of HttpStatusCode (in ASP.NET?
For example I get "HttpStatusCode.NotFound" I would like get error code 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast it to `int` :

```
HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
int codeAsInteger = (int)statusCode;
```

Now `codeAsInteger` is `404`.

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to an integer

```
(int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really very easy